# NSOutlineView Changing disclosure Image

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsoutlineview, nscell

I my outline view, i am adding Custom cell, To drawing custom cell, i am referring example code , present in the Cocoa documentation

http://www.martinkahr.com/2007/05/04/nscell-image-and-text-sample/

I want to change the disclosure image of the cell with my custom image, i have tried following things

```
- (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView willDisplayCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item 
    {
        if([item isKindOfClass:[NSValue class]])
        {
            MyData *pDt = (MyData *)[item pointerValue];
            if(pDt->isGroupElement())
            {
                [cell setImage:pGroupImage];
            }
        }
}
```

but that too not working, Is there any other way to change the disclosure image,
also how can i find out in willDisplayCell whether Item is expand or collapse, so i can set the image accordingly,

Is this only the place to change the disclosure image ?

Comment: For some reason my outline:willDisplayOutlineCell.... is never called. Any suggestions?

Comment: For a complete custom example - check out https://github.com/johndpope/TreeTest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the basic idea but what you will need to do is draw the image yourself. Here's the code I use:

```
- (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView willDisplayOutlineCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {
    NSString *theImageName;
    NSInteger theCellValue = [cell integerValue];
    if (theCellValue==1) {
        theImageName = @"PMOutlineCellOn";
    } else if (theCellValue==0) {
        theImageName = @"PMOutlineCellOff";
    } else {
        theImageName = @"PMOutlineCellMixed";
    }

    NSImage *theImage = [NSImage imageNamed: theImageName];
    NSRect theFrame = [outlineView frameOfOutlineCellAtRow:[outlineView rowForItem: item]];
    theFrame.origin.y = theFrame.origin.y +17;
    // adjust theFrame here to position your image
    [theImage compositeToPoint: theFrame.origin operation:NSCompositeSourceOver];
    [cell setImagePosition: NSNoImage];
}
```

You will need 3 different images as you can see, one for the `ON` state, one for the `OFF` state and also one for the `MIXED` state which should be halfway between the two. The mixed state makes sure you still get the opening and closing animation.

Comment: have done the way you suggest, but getting some issue, whether item expanded or collapse, always thecellvalue == 1 and this code is drawing image over the disclosure image, so if my image is transparent, then it will display the disclosure image also

Comment: `theCellValue` should never always be equal to 1 and it seems to work fine for me. The image should also not be shown which is what `[cell setImagePosition: NSNoImage];` does and again it works fine with me. I'm not sure why this is happening (unless you're doing something else to the cell) so I'm unable to provide any further help. Sorry. :(

Comment: thanks for the reply, actually i am using ImageTextCell which is subclassed from NSTextFieldCell and it throws unrecognized exception for setImagePosition, Probably that would be culprit, but no issue, as i was able to achieved with another approach.

Comment: It makes me nervous to draw within a method that is not expected to draw anything, so I prefer Scott Allen's answer.

Comment: @JWWalker I agree, this was a couple of years ago but I do agree with you. Drawing should be avoided in the `willDisplayOutlineCell` method if possible.

Answer (score 5):

After researching this issue myself, and trying some of the answers here, I have found that the other approaches mentioned will work, but will require that you perform a lot more manual intervention in order to avoid screen artifacts and other strange behavior.

The simplest solution I found is the following, which should work in most cases.

This solution has the added benefit of the system automatically handling a great many other cases, such as column movement, etc, without your involvement.

```
- (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView willDisplayOutlineCell:(id)cell
     forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
               item:(id)item
{
    [cell setImage:[NSImage imageNamed: @"Navigation right 16x16 vWhite_tx"]];
    [cell setAlternateImage:[NSImage imageNamed: @"Navigation down 16x16 vWhite_tx"]];
}
```

In your case, you would wrap this up with your class detection logic, and set the cell images appropriately for your cases.

Answer (score 3):

A nice way to change the disclosure image is to use a view based outline view:

In your ViewController with NSOutlineViewDelegate:

```
- (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item
{
    CustomNSTableCellView *cell    = [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];
    cell.item                      = item;

    return cell;
}
```

You have to subclass your NSOutlineView and overide the method:

```
- (id)makeViewWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier owner:(id)owner
{
    id view = [super makeViewWithIdentifier:identifier owner:owner];

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:NSOutlineViewDisclosureButtonKey])
    {
        // Do your customization
        // return disclosure button view

        [view setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"Disclosure_Categories_Plus"]];
        [view setAlternateImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"Disclosure_Categories_Minus"]];
        [view setBordered:NO];
        [view setTitle:@""];

        return view;
    }

    return view;
}

//Frame of the disclosure view
- (NSRect)frameOfOutlineCellAtRow:(NSInteger)row
{
    NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(4, (row * 22), 19, 19);
    return frame;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For who looks for Swift2 Solution. Subclass NSRow of your outlineview and override didAddSubview method as below.

```
override func didAddSubview(subview: NSView) {
    super.didAddSubview(subview)
    if let sv = subview as? NSButton {
        sv.image = NSImage(named:"IconNameForCollapsedState")
        sv.alternateImage = NSImage(named:"IconNameForExpandedState")
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been looking for this for hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have tried and working so far,

/* because we are showing our own disclose and expand button */

```
- (NSRect)frameOfOutlineCellAtRow:(NSInteger)row {

    return NSZeroRect;
}
- (NSRect)frameOfCellAtColumn:(NSInteger)column row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSRect superFrame = [super frameOfCellAtColumn:column row:row];

    if ((column == 0) && ([self isGroupItem:[self itemAtRow:row]])) {
        return NSMakeRect(0, superFrame.origin.y, [self bounds].size.width, superFrame.size.height);
    }
    return superFrame;
}
```

I have subclassed NSOutlineView class and override these methods,

[self isGroupItem] is to check whether its group or not. 
but got one problem, now looks like mousehandling i need to do :( , on double clicking group row is not toggling